# Creating new ObjectId using ``mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId`` is not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, populate, objectid

I have created a Mongoose schema and added the `studentId` field type as `studentId: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Student'},`, the purpose of populating that collection.

The populating part was done and it's working fine. But when I create a new document (in studentClass)—I have send `studentId` field as a `String` because of that—I have to try to convert `String` to `ObjectId` as follows,

```
const studentObjectId = mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId(studentId);
```

Using the above method was not working for me. Also, it did not trigger any errors. It seems like it is not compiling the code after that line.

I have also imported Mongoose as `const mongoose = require('mongoose');`

`studentClass` model as follows,

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const studentClassModel = new Schema({
    studentId: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Student'},
    groupId: {type: String}
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('StudentClass', studentClassModel, 'STUDENT_CLASS')
```

Answer (score 4):

`mongoose.Schema.Types` are for declaring schema.

`mongoose.Types` are for constructing those types.

Use

```
const studentObjectId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(studentId);
```

Comment: Can you please take a look on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77540162/unable-to-fetch-a-field-from-a-table-in-react/77540481?noredirect=1#comment136699940_77540481